# iOS 13 - Saving UIImage with wrong orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, phphotolibrary

I am facing some issues with the orientation of the photos.
After taking a portrait picture and saving it to the camera roll, I see it rotated. But when I add it to an Image View it looks ok.
Anyone else found the same issue? Is there an open bug in the Feedback Assistant?
Thanks!

Same issue happened when I tried to save it using the PHPhotoLibrary

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil); //Saves rotated
    imageView.image = image; //Appears OK
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

```
PHAssetChangeRequest *changeRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromImage:image];
assetPlaceholder = changeRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset;
```

Answer (score -1):

I have this extension in my project. Try it.

```
extension UIImage {
    func fixOrientation() -> UIImage {
        if imageOrientation == .up {
            return self
        }
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, scale)
        draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
        let normalizedImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() ?? self
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return normalizedImage
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. The question is tagged Objective-C, not Swift. Please post answers in the proper language. 2. Please don't post code-only answers. A good answer explains what was wrong in the question and it explains how the answer solves the problem.